# Duplicated object still has parent material when exported to fbx

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I duplicated (using Shift+d) and created 3 arrows from an arrow(This had a purple color). In Blender, the three new arrows have different colors, but when I export these objects to fbx format and use them in Unity, they still show with the parent's purple color.

[image: Blender to the left and unity to the right]

Tried the following

1. tried un-linking the objects by pressing U and selecting Object & Data & Materials + Tex.
2. Verified that there is no link by going into the mesh tab for the object. (Saw that if there is a "2" beside the "F", it means that it is linked)

[image: Mesh tab]

3. Created different materials for each of the arrows.
4. Verified online that the exported object has the purple color and not Unity issue.

I might be missing something trivial, but I was stuck here for the past 30 minutes.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Unity not Blender. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thanks Ramos, I will use the blend file directly instead. And copy the materials from the auto-generated folder in Unity